# Symfony2 Doctrine - create primary width two fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine, composite-primary-key

I am triying to set a Primary Key in my entity 'Grupo', that must be composed width two fields: 'id_grupo' and 'id_estudiante'. I don't know how to do it. Need help please. Thanks!

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields = {"id_grupo", "id_estudiante", "nombre_grupo"})
 * @DoctrineAssert\
*/
class Grupo
{
    /**
     *  @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *  @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
    protected $id_grupo;

   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Estudiante", inversedBy="grupos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="estudiante_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $id_estudiante;  // Estudiante propietario del grupo

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) */
    protected $nombre_grupo;
```

}

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields = {"id", "guid"})
*/
class Estudiante implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     *  @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
     *  @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Por favor, indica tu email")
     *  @Assert\Email(message = "El email introducido no es válido",
     *                checkMX=true)
     *  @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Estudiante", mappedBy="mis_amigos")
    */
    protected $id_estudiante;

    (...)

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Grupo", mappedBy="id_estudiante")
     **/
    protected $grupos;
```

}

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can do something like this (not checked so you need to check it :) ):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Grupo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Estudiante")
     */
    private $estudiante;
}
```

For sure you need to read about [Composite and Foreign keys in doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-3-join-table-with-metadata)